# get variable from a jQuery Plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

I need to know how is possible to get a plugin variable outside the plugin, to test it with some test framework.

So this is my simplified plugin:

```
(function ($) {
    $.fn.extend({      
        myPlugin: function (argumentOptions) {
            var defaults = {
                image: 'img/default.png',
            };

            this.textSend = '';

            var options = $.extend(defaults, argumentOptions);
            var globalHere = this;

            return this.each(function () {
                obj.mouseup(function(e) {
                    globalHere.textSend = 'test';
                });
            });
        }
    });     
})(jQuery);
```

I need to the variable `this.textSend` outside the plugin.

I have tried in this way:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

  var testfield = $('.txt');

  testfield.myPlugin({
      image:"../img/twitter.png"
  });

  testfield.focus();
  testfield.trigger($.Event( "mouseup"));
  console.log($.fn.myPlugin.textSend);
});
```

but the `console.log` return me `undefined`

How can i get that variable outside?

Thanks

Comment: Why don't you just expose a getter method for the variable you want to read?

Comment: can you please provide an answer with an example with it please? @elio.d

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will want to make sure you are returning `this` like so:

```js
(function($) {
  $.fn.extend({
    myPlugin: function(argumentOptions) {
      var self = this;
      
      self.textSend = 'something';
      self.inc = 0;
      
      self.mouseup(function(e) {
        self.textSend = 'new thing #' + self.inc;
        self.inc++;
      });

      return self;
    }
  });
})(jQuery);

var instantiated = $('button').myPlugin({});
$('input').val(instantiated.textSend);

$('button').click(function(e) {
  $('input').val(instantiated.textSend);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label>Current textSend:</label>
<input />
<br/>
<button>Change textSend</button>
```

Hopefully will get you on the right track.

**Update**
Try new code.

Comment: Ok now I get it, the problem is now: if I assign a default value I seen always this it doesn't take a new value if I'll update it inside the this.each loop, return always the same default value

Comment: I'm not sure the context of `this` is what you think it is. But you probably want to do this... let me update answer

Comment: with new eedit return always 'something' not 'new thing' but i'm sure to enter into mouseup because I put inside the function a console.log

Comment: You had to click the element for it to update `textSend`, I updated with a button to be more clear ;)

Comment: yes but the context is different and I have an each loop, i'll trigger it on every mouseup but I can have more elements for this I have an each loop that return it if you seen my plugin code

Comment: What is the purpose of the each loop? It is redundant since you are working with jQuery which will loop through already.

Comment: The ourpose is to loop every element that call the plugin, if I have more instance of the plugin

Comment: Sorry, I don't know how I can be more clear. I've more than answered the question.

Comment: I know and I have appreciated your help, but the plugin is different with that each loop,  without it isn't a problem and your code works fine!

Answer (score 1):

You can store it inside the closed scope you created around your plugin and expose it through another function. Of course it'll need some refactoring, but this is the general idea:

```
(function ($) {
    var whateverNameYouWant; //here

    $.fn.extend({      
        myPlugin: function (argumentOptions) {
            var defaults = {
                image: 'img/default.png',
            };

            this.textSend = '';
            whateverNameYouWant = this.textSend; //here

            var options = $.extend(defaults, argumentOptions);
            var globalHere = this;

            return this.each(function () {
                obj.mouseup(function(e) {
                    globalHere.textSend = 'test';
                    whateverNameYouWant = this.textSend; //here
                });
            });
        }
    });     

    $.extend({
        getWhateverNameYouWant: function() {
            return whateverNameYouWant;
        }
    })
})(jQuery);



var value = $.getWhateverNameYouWant();
```

Answer (score 0):

At line console.log($.fn.myPlugin.textSend);

use testfield.textSend . now it has become proprty of selector via myplugin.

Comment: return undefined again